# Can't figure out how to print first item/image of an array from the database - PHP / HTML

Tags: php, html

I try to print the first item of an array of images in the database. But every time I try to only get the first image. It prints out all the images or nothing at all.

All the images get the same occID when they are uploaded.

```
<div id="content">
<?php
$sql = new sql();
$result = $cars->getCarsByID($_GET['occID']);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {?>
<div class="occasion infopage">
    <div> <br></div>

    <div class="car_bg_moreinfo">

        <div class="car_holder">
            <div class="photo_holder">
                <?php 
                        $result = $file->getFilesByOccId($row->ID);
                        while($rile = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>

                <a href="car_images/<?php echo $rile->file; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery"><img class="rounded" src="car_images/100_<?php echo $rile->file  ; ?>" width="125" height="100" border="0" style="object-fit: cover;" /></a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

I tried it with [0] after $result function, but that doenst seem to work.. What am i doing wrong?

I am really not experienced in PHP. Hope anyone can help.

Comment: Perhaps you should not reuse `$result`

Comment: `while($rile =` -> `if($rile =`...then it will just fetch the first item returned by the query, if any, and won't loop through all of them.

Comment: And yeah, don't re-use the same variable (`$result` in this case) for two different things, that's a recipe for unpredictable and hard-to-debug behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Comment by ADyson worked:

`while($rile = -> if($rile =...` then it will just fetch the first item returned by the query, if any, and won't loop through all of them.

I replaced while with if.